# How to verify method is only ever called with expected arguments?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'd like to verify that calls against a mock only ever happen with some expected argument values, and never with anything else.

```
public interface ADependancy {
    public void method(String parameter, String otherParameter);
}


public class Foo {
    private ADependancy myHelper;

    public Foo(ADependancy helper) {
        this.myHelper = helper;
    }

    public void good() {
        myHelper.method("expected","expected");
        myHelper.method("expected","expected");
        myHelper.method("expected","expected");
    }

    public void bad() {
        myHelper.method("expected","expected");
        myHelper.method("expected","UNexpected");
        myHelper.method("expected","expected");
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
public class FooTest extends TestCase {
    private ADependancy mock =mock(ADependancy.class);;
    private Foo foo  = new Foo(mock);

    @Test
    public void testGood() {
        foo.good();
        validateOnlyCalledWithExpected();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBad() {
        foo.bad();
        validateOnlyCalledWithExpected();
    }

    private void validateOnlyCalledWithExpected() {
        verify(mock,atLeastOnce()).method(eq("expected"),eq("expected"));
        verify(mock,never()).method(not(eq("expected")),not(eq("expected")));
    }
}
```

Expecting testBad to fail, but instead the test passes.  If method only takes one parameter, this works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a logic mistake.

I wanted to assert that each argument is never anything but the expected value.
But instead, what I was actually asserting was that it never happens that they are ALL not the expected value.
So with the way I had it, it did not fail as desired, because in fact, *some* of the arguments are not *not* the expected value, therefore the method *is never* called with *all* the parameters *not* the expected value, and the verify passes.

Thus, this works for what I wanted:

```
    private void validateOnlyCalledWithExpected() {
        verify(mock,atLeastOnce()).method(eq("expected"),eq("expected"));
        verify(mock,never()).method(not(eq("expected")),anyString());
        verify(mock,never()).method(anyString(),not(eq("expected")));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `verifyNoMoreInteractions` static method, documented at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#finding_redundant_invocations.

```
verify(mock).method(eq("expected"),eq("expected"));
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
```

Alternatively, you could write

```
verify(mock).method(eq("expected"),eq("expected"));
verify(mock,never()).method(anyString(),anyString());
```

because the second call to `verify` will disregard the calls that have already been verified.

Comment: I'd like this better, but it doesn't seem to work for my example.  Perhaps it is the fact that I am calling method more than once? (See the "atLeastOnce" );

Comment: OK, then put the `atLeastOnce()` in.  I didn't bother typing that because it was clear from your question that you already knew how to use `atLeastOnce()`.

Comment: No, I meant that it literally doesn't work, when I plug in you code to my example, then _both_ tests fail... OK upon further inspection your first snippit _does_ appear to work as desired.  It is just second snippit which doesn't work.

Comment: Really?  OK, I'll re-test it and try to find out what's going on.  This won't be today though; I'm busy.

Comment: I was not able to go with solution 1 since I need to interact with other methods on the mock.
And solution 2 did not work for some reason.

Comment: @Anders OK, what was the problem with solution 2?  Some error message?  Did it just fail silently?  If you can tell me what issue you faced, I may be able to help you fix it.